# Chrome 65 can't print hidden iframe

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, iframe

I stumbled upon what seems to be a Chrome 65 bug regarding `iframes`.

I can't use a snippet to demonstrate this, so I used this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7y3b4e4/11/).

The problem is that if the `iframe` is `display: none;`, the `.print()` on said `iframe` won't print anything.

It only happens on Chrome 65, not Chrome 64.

Here is the code :

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" class="hidden"></iframe>
<button class="db">Print without display: none;</button>
<button class="dn">Print with display: none;</button>

$('.db').on('click',function(){
    $('#frame').contents().find('body').append('<p>Test without <code>display: none;</code>!</p>')
  $('#frame')[0].contentWindow.print();
});

$('.dn').on('click',function(){
    $('#frame2').contents().find('body').append('<p>Test with <code>display: none;</code>!</p>')
  $('#frame2')[0].contentWindow.print();
});

.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

PS : Don't try to edit this into a snippet, the iframes don't work inside them.

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/ed06b93000c86b85c098703b0763862e0ff9a699..94a4da6e66192395e9d3ab9c44eee42150bb0865 — DisplayNoneIFrameCreatesNoLayoutObject seems relevant.

Comment: @JoshLee Thanks, but I must say I have no idea what to do about this information !

Comment: I'm assuming you expect the display none iframe to print when explicitly printed? This is still broken on the beta version of Chrome (66), but it works in the canary version (67), so it looks like this will be fixed.

Comment: @Necreaux Good to know it's not just expected behavior, thanks !

Answer (score 9):

This *may* have been a deliberate change, but I don't know enough to say for sure. The change seems to have been https://crrev.com/526112 if you want to go exploring; there was some fallout from Google Docs so you're not alone in trying to work around this.

I can work around it by using

```
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
```

on the iframe to simulate the effect of `display: none` taking it out of the normal flow but still allowing it to perform its own layout. https://jsfiddle.net/28w1tomv/

Comment: *sigh* I have so many modules working with `iframes` like this, it's annoying to see this mechanism change without any warning ... Thanks for the tip anyway, I'll let the question open for a while in hope someone has a definitive answer.

Comment: Just confirming that I have had the exact same issue as described, and this solution has also worked for me!